# Add fake column to Linq Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 2 table : Singer and Song like this

[image]

I need to retrieve songs from 1 singer, or just retrieve a song by it id , I use this:

```
db.Songs.Find(id);                      // get song by its ID
db.Songs.Where(x => x.SingerID == id);  // get all songs by singer's ID
```

and it return that song

```
$id: "2",
Id: 1,
NAME: "....",
IMAGE: ".....jpg",
URL: ".....mp3",
SingerID: 1
```

but I want to hide the SingerID, instead I want to return a "SingerName" column.  I've used this:

```
db.Songs.Where(x => x.SingerID == id).Select(song => new { song, song.Singer.NAME });
```

but the result became:

```
song: {
    $id: "2",
    Id: 1,
    NAME: "....",
    IMAGE: ".....jpg",
    URL: ".....mp3",
    SingerID: 1
}
NAME: "SingerName"
```

So how can I get the result like this - all properties are equal (hide the SingerID and replace by SingerName):

```
$id: "2",
Id: 1,
NAME: "....",
IMAGE: ".....jpg",
URL: ".....mp3",
SingerName: "SingerName etc"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db.Songs.Where(x => x.SingerID == id).Select(song => new { song.Name, song.Image, etc... , SingerName = song.Singer.NAME });
```

Comment: yes, but if when I need to change my Song table (i.e add a new "LinkShare" column to Song ), I have to update all my queries with new properties ?

Comment: yes, because in this case you are creating a new anonymous object. Also, that might be a good habit to get into (specifying the columns returned) to minimise the amount of data being returned. For example, what if someone else adds a bunch of other columns to the table that you DO NOT in this case want returned in your query.

Answer (score 2):

You can just create new anonymous object and pass whatever you want.

`db.Songs.Where(x => x.SingerID == id).Select(song => new {
  Id,
  NAME,
  IMAGE,
  URL,
  SingerName = song.Singer.NAME
});`